# Display template in front-end

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I followed the tutorial of Inchoo for Magento

How to add custom contact form with email notification I added the files as mentioned now i need to know how to display it in front-end.

Tutorial link: inchoo.net/magento/magento-email/magento-custom-email-contact-form-with-notification-system/

Regards,

Comment: In front-end but where do you want to display?
currently, it will be at `http://127.0.0.1/magento/inchoo-simplecontact`

Comment: I created cms page and want to display the form in it

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your cms page

```
{{block type="core/template" name="simple_contact_form" form_action="/inchoo-simplecontact/index/sendemail" template="inchoo/simple_contact.phtml"}}
```

Check `app\code\local\Inchoo\SimpleContact\controllers\IndexController.php`

there is `sendemailAction()` and in it at last `$this->_redirect('inchoo-simplecontact/');` this will redirect. So may you want to change redirect it's here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply i added the code and still no form displays in the cms page

Comment: That's strange... because I did that same thing in my local Magento project and it was showing.